# Can I get infected again with the same cold?

Tags: infection, common-cold

Both me and my mom got infected with cold from the same person apparently, since both of us fell ill a few days after meeting this ill at that time person.

However, mom got infected far more severely than me apparently, since I’m recovering right now w/o any help from the Doctor, while mom lies with fever, two weeks of sick leave, antibiotics, and diagnosed bronchitis and tonsillitis.

Today I had to help her with a few things. This involved a few hours of sitting with her in her room, touching her things, etc. Now I wonder, can I get re-infected from her with the same cold? Is it possible that I’m going to get as bad as she is now, or maybe since I’m still not completely healthy yet and therefore the same germs are in my body as well at the moment it doesn’t really matter, and if I were to get infected that badly, I already would’ve?

Comment: Nobody can give you a yes/no answer but the most likely answer is no, don't worry about it. You won't get the cold again for sure, but you could get the other infection she probably has now so be careful about washing your hands.